# BUG: time.Time does not Omit when Empty

Tags: go, mgo

This is a BUG I've read up on, wondering if anyone has a particular suggestion for my use-case, since I'm not sure when it's going to get fixed (last I read 1.4).

I'm decoding JSON into the following struct:

```
User struct {
    ID_  bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id,omitempty"`
    UTC *time.Time     `bson:"utc,omitempty" json:"utc,omitempty"`
    USR  string        `bson:"usr,omitempty" json:"usr,omitempty"`
    PWD  string        `bson:"pwd,omitempty" json:"pwd,omitempty"`
}
```

And then updating the USR and PWD fields using MGO:

```
func save(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  m := s.Copy()
  defer m.Close()
  user := m.DB("0").C("user")
  var a User
  json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&a)
  b := &User {USR:a.USR, PWD:a.PWD}
  user.UpdateId(a.ID_, b)
}
```

When I have time.Time in struct definition, I get a zero date value, this resets my date in my Mongo Doc back to UNIX start. When I use *time.Time, I get a nil date value, which completely erases my date field from my Mongo Doc. Here's the code:

Any ideas how to make this work? I'd rather not create a new struct for each call -- it's nice to essentially reuse my User struct (which is essentially my DB collection schema).

CURRENT STATE:

Some great comments, and work-around solutions, thanks all. However, I'm still confused about the inconsistent behavior of "omitempty". When it's a string && empty it's truly omitted form the struct post Decode. However, when it's a time.Time/bson.ObjectId it's zeroed when empty OR *time.Time/*bson.ObjectId it's nil when empty. It'd be really nice if they were truly omitted. Then we could reuse the struct over and over again (without needing to be ultra explicit -- which is basically additional work to get around those nil/zeroed values).

Comment: Not that this is really answering your question.. but have you thought about performing a manual update of those two fields instead of using the "blanket update" API `UpdateId`?

Comment: To clarify.. I mean something like `user.Update(bson.M{"ObjectId": a.ID_}, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"usr": a.USR, "pwd": a.PWD}})`

Comment: Thanks for the insight. That works, but being that explicit is nearly as much work as defining a new struct. I hope all the fuss with 'Type' pays off - I'm coming from Node where all this stuff is easy-mode... i.e. JSON is native... although, I have to say... I love being able to write a for loop again vs. async.blah.blah.blah

Comment: This issue also complicates this call:user.Find(a).Select(bson.M{"_id":1}).One(&b). Where ideally I could just var a,b User... the nil or Zero time.Time get in the way, so I have to create a temp struct just for that call...

Comment: Its not really a Go thing though... its more a Mongo thing. Update replaces the document... unless you specify $set. There may be a way to do it with the mgo driver where it uses $set for you. I will have a look.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way to do this in the driver. I would say my comment is actually your answer.. you need to manually pass $set.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve the same thing with user.Find(a)? In this case, it pulls back data docs where UTC = 0 or nil. I get that I could probably be explicit here as well... but isn't that the point of omitempty... convenience. If it simply did what it said (omitted the field altogether -- like it does with most fields) life would be so much easier.

Comment: you can't have a struct member with no value. UTC 0 respectively nil are the zero-values for the given field. what value would you expect to get when omitempty omits a field?

Comment: Hi Tom. It's also a problem for the ID_ field (it's nil when omitted). The behavior I expect is like what happens to USR + PSW. when those are empty, they literally don't exist in the struct (they are not just zeroed out or nil).